# How to type @ Chraacter when installing OSX?

Tags: macos

I tried to reinstall OSX El Capitan on my MBP.

At some point i shall enter my apple-id which contains an @-character.
However, i was unable to type this character.

How to type this character "@" in this case?

I have this model: "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the shift key and press the 2 key, the one with an `@` over it.